# How to make a date picker non selectable (read-only) after press a button

Tags: ionic3

Now I have a date-picker,
I want to make it becomes read-only after I pick a day and pressing confirm button.
Now I can put the that I pick into a label.
What should I do ?

```
<button ion-button outline icon-right (click)="openit()">
  <ion-label>{{date}}</ion-label>
  <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
```

I just want to see the date without the icon

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you are clicking the button to open the date picker?

For this case, you can set the disabled state of the button to `true` and stop it from being used in the future, or until the page reloads etc.

Add a disabled property into your `<button...` line such as:

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="disabled" outline icon-right (click)="openit()">
```

You will then need to amend your `openit()` method by adding the following:

```
this.disabled="true";
```

Let me know if this works :-)

Comment: If you have used a different solution, you can post your own answer and accept it (in 2 days time), just to help other people in future :-)

Comment: I use this 
 <button ion-button outline icon-right (click)="openit()" *ngIf="checkstatus">
      <ion-label>{{date}}</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
  </button>
and set a button to change checkstatus to true or false

Comment: Aha, using Angular properly I see ;-)